# Django caches API requests results

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

When developing an app locally using Django, I do `runserver` and I work locally.

The issue that I have is that most of the time the GET requests to the API are cached, and therefore when I do for example a Patch or Update, it does not reflect results.

Example:

```
GET django.app/api/v1/cars
Returns: {id: 1, is_active: True}



PATCH {'is_active': False} django.app/api/v1/cars/1/
Returns: {id: 1, is_active: False}


GET django.app/api/v1/cars
Returns(cached): {id: 1, is_active: True}
```

Is there a setting for this? or could it be a browser issue? I had a similar issue on the server nginx and I disabled the cached from the server side, but since locally I am using the runserver from Django, I don't know if there is such a setting.

Note that I am using out of the box django.

Edit: adding some code as requested in the comments:

```
models.py
    class Car(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = u"tbl_car"
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
        id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True, db_column='id')
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)


api/v1/views.py

class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CarSerializer
    permission_classes = [custom_permissions.IsSuperUserOrUserReadOnly]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['is_active']
```

api/v1/serializes.py

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Car
        fields = '__all__'
```

api/v1/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('cars', views.CarViewSet)
```

Comment: What does the code for the `api/v1/cars/1` view look like?

Comment: Have you setup the admin for that model?  Does the value displayed in the admin match what is returned by the API?  That'll help you figure out if it's a caching problem or a database update problem.

Comment: It does save in DB properly, it is just that if I do get again, it gets the cached value.